# Получение индекса двумерного массива

Tags: java

Добрый день! Споткнулся на вроде бы несложной задачке - как вывести индекс члена двумерного массива - например, из члена `mass[4][10]` получить `int a = 4; int b = 10;` Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Массив хранит ссылки на свои элементы, а вот сами элементы никак не хранят информации о том, являются ли они вообще частью массива. Поэтому единственный способ, полный перебор массива со сравнением его членов на эквивалентность заданному.

```
for(int i=0; i<mass.length; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<mass[i].length; j++)
        if(obj == mass[i][j]) System.out.printf("%d %d", i, j);
```

P.S. Я не знаю как ведут себя в Java элементы созданные по ссылке и по значению с методом Equals, поэтому думаю данный код может представлять проблемы при переборе простых типов.

Comment: Во-первых, если ищется конкретный элемнт, то надо проверять равенство по ссылке через `==`, а не по значению через `equals`. Во-вторых, никто не запрещает размещать в массиве одинаковые элементы. Имея один из элементов, который встречается в массиве более одного раза, невозможно определить, где именно этот элемент находится.

Comment: `length`, а не `lenght`

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо, поправил ошибки. Про одинаковые элементы и про сравнение простых типов по значению я в курсе, но это единственный нормальный вариант, который можно хоть как-то применить.

Answer (score -1):

Это невозможно. Если только ты не сделал специальный класс с индексами, который и сложил в массив.

Comment: Спасибо всем! Поищу другой алгоритм.

Comment: @Арнольд, второе предложение внимательнее прочитай ;)